# JQuery: How to hide an image until source changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, show-hide

I have an image that is being resized programmatically, based on the current height/width of the container. My problem is that it shows the image at it's original size before it does the resizing.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ev4YL/1/)

You'll notice how it flashes up a stretched image before it fits the image nicely in the middle.

I want to hide the image until that resizing has taken place, but I can't figure out how.

Any suggestions?

JSCode:

```
function LoadImg(img) {
    img.css('visibility','hidden');
    var src=img.attr('src');
    var imgh = img.parent().height();
    var imgw = img.parent().width();
    var pattern = /&?(w|h)=[^&]+/g;
    src = src.replace(pattern, '');
    img.attr('src', src + '&w=' + imgw + '&h=' + imgh);    
    img.css('visibility','');
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="window">
<img src="http://www.angclassiccarparts.co.uk/image_anysize.aspx?f=/images/ww/panel/service_kits.jpg&w=154&h=154&color=png" id="img" onload="LoadImg($(this));" />
</div>
```

I've tried hiding with visibility hidden until the function has run, but that doesn't wait for it to load...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're changing the source of the image, which forces it to load a new image, then you instantly set the image to visible.

Ultimately you want to wait until the second image is loaded before showing it, which can be achieved using `.load()` like so:

```
img.on('load', function() {
    img.css('visibility','visible');
});
```

Here's an updated jsFiddle with the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/ev4YL/2/

I would, however, recommend a different approach. It doesn't make much sense to load an image, then when it's loaded load another image. Perhaps you should store the dimensions in html data attributes, then load the images dynamically on document.ready.

Something like this could work, if you set each image to have a `data-src` instead of `src` to begin with:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var img = $(this);

    var src = img.attr('data-src');
    var imgh = img.parent().height();
    var imgw = img.parent().width();
    var pattern = /&?(w|h)=[^&]+/g;
    src = src.replace(pattern, '');
    img.attr('src', src + '&w=' + imgw + '&h=' + imgh);    

    img.on('load', function() {
        img.css('visibility','visible');
    });
});
```

And the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ev4YL/4/

Comment: that's creating a kind of infinite loop here, i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ev4YL/3/

Comment: It is called on a `$(window).resize` function in my actual project. The dimensions of it's container are based upon height and width of browser window. It's weird how this works, called an img onload function from within another img onload function. I wouldn't have thought of this, thanks :)

Comment: @JamieBarker wait, don't use it, A. Wolff is right, it continuously fires the load event. Give me a sec to fix it.

Comment: I think it would be better to ditch the onload event in the html, and just use something like this (which also accounts for resizing): http://jsfiddle.net/ev4YL/7/. Having said that, why do you need to load new images on resize? What's wrong with just resizing it using HTML/CSS?

Comment: Seems to only be looping in IE, typical... it resizes the image to fit withing the boundaries, but keeps aspect ratio.

Comment: Actually my answer was _still_ binding heaps of load events haha, try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ev4YL/10/. You could also try using background images and using `background-size: cover`, or funnily enough I even wrote a jQuery plugin that does what you want. Either of those would be better than loading new images on resize. http://christianvarga.com/jquery-resize-image-to-parent-container-plugin/

Comment: @JamieBarker actually, what you want to achieve can be done using CSS alone with `max-width: 100%` and `max-height: 100%`. Just make sure you load images that are big enough to fit the largest size. For example, here's a pure CSS version: http://jsfiddle.net/ev4YL/11/

Comment: My images are pulled straight out the database in the aspx file based on an item selected in a dropdown. The image is also loaded in the first instance via an AJAX call so window.load isn't an option either.

Comment: The other reason is that some stupid customer(s) might decide to upload a logo of hugely ridiculous proportions into the database. Programmatically resizing means the huge image loads a lot quicker and no awful pixelation occurs.

Comment: @JamieBarker Then you should just resize the image once when it's first uploaded, to a couple of different dimensions (check how Wordpress does it). I know you're trying to do the right thing, but in 7 years of web development, I've never needed to, nor even seen a website or app that resizes images to specific dimensions on the window.resize event. I guarantee you that your problem can be solved more efficiently, and I would highly recommend posting another StackOverflow question to get some ideas from the community on how to best tackle this problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52221/discussion-between-jamie-barker-and-christian-varga)

Comment: Managed to get it working with help from @ChristianVarga - http://jsfiddle.net/ev4YL/15/

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the image with display: none until the end of the function, then set the image to display: block (or whatever you need) at the very end. That way the rest of the function has already run, when it displays it will have already been resized.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rufWy/)

But basically just:
CSS:

```
img {
  display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function loadImg(img) {
  ----all of your function here----
  img.css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: Can't do this. Used visibility hidden because it keeps the elements around it in place.